# Spring MVC clears status.value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

Does spring MVC clears status.value when the bind element has errors? if so, how can I retrieve the value using the status element?

So I have this:

```
<c:forEach var="field" items="${fieldList}">
    <spring:bind path="myBean.${field.fieldName}">
        <input type="text" class="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${status.value}" />
        <span id="${status.expression}Error" class="error">
            <c:forEach items="${status.errorMessages}" var="error">
                <c:out value="${error}" />
            </c:forEach>
        </span>
    </spring:bind>
</c:forEach>
```

But every time `field` contains validation erros the value of the input `${status.value}` is `null`. I'm sure it's there because accessing through `${myBean.fieldName}` does the job. But my issue is because of the iteration I'm doing, I can't do that.

Comment: `status` is variable used with spring:bind. More info here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/taglib/tag/BindTag.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally got it. Instead of `${status.value}` I used `${myBean[field.fieldName]}` to access directly to the field value.

```
<c:forEach var="field" items="${fieldList}">
    <spring:bind path="myBean.${field.fieldName}">
        <input type="text" class="text" name="${status.expression}" value="${myBean[field.fieldName]}" />
        <span id="${status.expression}Error" class="error">
            <c:forEach items="${status.errorMessages}" var="error">
                <c:out value="${error}" />
            </c:forEach>
        </span>
    </spring:bind>
</c:forEach>
```